# How to import a node_modules dependency for use in a frontend ES6 module

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6

I'm playing around with ES6 syntax and would like to build a small module in NPM, which uses another npm module (e.g. push-js) as a dependency. Currently, I'm using rollup to bundle and generate my distribution files.

I'm not sure what's the right way to include a dependency in order to use it in my own module. This is what I tried

```
import * as Push from 'push.js';

class _MyModule
{
    Push.create("Go ahead, click this notification", {
      
    });
}
```

Rollup triggers the following error on this code:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Unexpected token
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close enough. However, at least in current transpilers (Babel and co.), CommonJS module exports are treated like default exports. Meaning, instead of importing all separate entities (`import * as Push`), you only have to import the default exports (`import Push`).

```
import Push from 'push.js';

class _MyModule
{
    constructor() {
        Push.create("Go ahead, click this notification", {

        });
    }
}
```

How the actual interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules will be solved, is not yet finalized. [See Axel Rauschmayr's blog post on the subject.](http://www.2ality.com/2017/01/babel-esm-spec-mode.html#native-es-modules-in-node.js)

Comment: I found out that I needed to add nodeResolve and commonjs (makes sense now) plugins in gulp to resolve the push library. Your comment helped me solved that. I still keep getting errors from the point where I try to use the "Push" object in my own module code. Any idea what's still missing?

Comment: So wait, this is about your gulp config? I have no idea what you problem could be, since I don't even know what your gulp code looks like.

Comment: Your answer solved the issue, thank you! After that, it was an error on my part, just look at my class which isn't the right syntax. Totally overlooked adding a function to the class which then calls push.create. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that as well… Thank you for pointing it out…